# if statements and the order it should be written

Tags: java, if-statement

I need to develop an algorithm to calculate the price of a ticket. First, the user have to input a price, seat location (Upper = 30% off, Middle = regular, Lower = 25% premium), and customer type (Senior = 10% off, Adult = regular).

So a sample test: User enters 50 for price, Upper for location and Senior for customer type, the final ticket price should be 31.50.

So far my algorithm gets me 35. Can someone find my mistake, please?

```
    if (cusType.charAt(0) == 'A'){
        ticPrice = regTicPrice;

        if (location.charAt(0) == 'U'){
            ticPrice = regTicPrice * 0.7;
        }
        else if (location.charAt(0) == 'L'){
            ticPrice = regTicPrice * 1.25;
        }
        else if (location.charAt(0) == 'M'){
            ticPrice = regTicPrice;
        }
    }

    else if (cusType.charAt(0) == 'S'){
        ticPrice = regTicPrice * 0.9;

        if (location.charAt(0) == 'U'){
            ticPrice = regTicPrice * 0.7;
        }
        else if (location.charAt(0) == 'L'){
            ticPrice = regTicPrice * 1.25;
        }
        else if (location.charAt(0) == 'M'){
            ticPrice = regTicPrice;
        }
    }
    else{
     ticPrice = 0;   
    }
```

Comment: ticPrice = regTicPrice * 0.7 should be ticPrice = ticPrice * 0.7;

Comment: Please use debugger in the future for this kind of question.

Comment: Ok, now I only get outputs for the second half of the if statement "if charAt(0) == 'S'" but not the char at 'A'

Answer (score 1):

Use a `HashMap` to make your life simpler, like this:

```
HashMap customerTypeDiscount = new HashMap<String, Double>();
customerTypeDiscount.put("Adult", 1);
customerTypeDiscount.put("Senior", 0.9);

HashMap locationDiscount = new HashMap<String, Double>();
locationDiscount.put("Upper", 0.7);
locationDiscount.put("Middle", 1);
locationDiscount.put("Lower", 1.25);

ticPrice = regTicPrice * ((Double) customerTypeDiscount.get(cusType)) * (((Double) locationDiscount.get(location));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue has to do with you updating the ticPrice but never reusing that updated ticPrice after being a senior member.

You end up doing 50 * .7 for "U" instead of 50 * .9 * .7.

```
if (cusType.charAt(0) == 'A'){
    ticPrice = regTicPrice;

    if (location.charAt(0) == 'U'){
        ticPrice = ticPrice * 0.7;
    }
    else if (location.charAt(0) == 'L'){
        ticPrice = ticPrice * 1.25;
    }
    else if (location.charAt(0) == 'M'){
        // you don't technically need this if statement at the end since it doesnt change
        ticPrice = ticPrice;
    }
}

else if (cusType.charAt(0) == 'S'){
    ticPrice = ticPrice * 0.9;

    if (location.charAt(0) == 'U'){
        ticPrice = ticPrice * 0.7;
    }
    else if (location.charAt(0) == 'L'){
        ticPrice = ticPrice * 1.25;
    }
    else if (location.charAt(0) == 'M'){
        // you dont technically need this if statement at the end since it doesnt change
        ticPrice = ticPrice;
    }
}
else{
 ticPrice = 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Actual price of ticket while calculating discounted price of ticket, use ticPrice in Inner If instead of regTicPrice sa below :

```
   if (cusType.charAt(0) == 'A'){
    ticPrice = regTicPrice;
    if (location.charAt(0) == 'U'){
        ticPrice = ticPrice * 0.7;
    }
    else if (location.charAt(0) == 'L'){
        ticPrice = ticPrice * 1.25;
    }
    else if (location.charAt(0) == 'M'){
        ticPrice = ticPrice;
    }
}

else if (cusType.charAt(0) == 'S'){
    ticPrice = regTicPrice * 0.9;

    if (location.charAt(0) == 'U'){
        ticPrice = ticPrice * 0.7;
    }
    else if (location.charAt(0) == 'L'){
        ticPrice = ticPrice * 1.25;
    }
    else if (location.charAt(0) == 'M'){
        ticPrice = ticPrice;
    }
}
else{
 ticPrice = 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this line of code you have written:

```
ticPrice = regTicPrice * 0.9;

    if (location.charAt(0) == 'U'){
        ticPrice = regTicPrice * 0.7;
    }
```

regTicPrice is 50

```
ticPrice =  regTicPrice * 0.9
```

now ticPrice has value = 50 * 0.9 = 45

Next line is

```
ticPrice = regTicPrice * 0.7
Wrong ==== ticPrice = 50 * 0.7 = 35
Right ==== ticPrice = 45 * 0.7 = 31.50
```

You are overriding ticPrice: with regTicPrice * 0.7

Code should be something like below

```
ticPrice = regTicPrice * 0.9;

    if (location.charAt(0) == 'U'){
        ticPrice = ticPrice * 0.7;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `float` data type for `ticPrice`, if you are already using it then try `ticPrice=(float)ticPrice * 0.9;`

Answer (score 0):

Refactoring and fixed

```
ticPrice = 0; 

if (cusType.charAt(0) == 'A')
    ticPrice = regTicPrice;
else if (cusType.charAt(0) == 'S')
    ticPrice = regTicPrice * 0.9;

if (ticPrice > 0) {
    if (location.charAt(0) == 'U')
        ticPrice = ticPrice * 0.7;
    else if (location.charAt(0) == 'L')
        ticPrice = ticPrice * 1.25;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use hashmap to store your information and pick from here

Answer (score 0):

if (cusType.charAt(0) == 'A'){
        ticPrice = regTicPrice;

```
    if (location.charAt(0) == 'U'){
        ticPrice = ticPrice * 0.7;      //you made mistake here..
    }
    else if (location.charAt(0) == 'L'){
        ticPrice = ticPrice * 1.25;
    }
    else if (location.charAt(0) == 'M'){
        ticPrice = regTicPrice;
    }
}

else if (cusType.charAt(0) == 'S'){
    ticPrice = regTicPrice * 0.9;

    if (location.charAt(0) == 'U'){
        ticPrice = ticPrice * 0.7;
    }
    else if (location.charAt(0) == 'L'){
        ticPrice = ticPrice * 1.25;
    }
    else if (location.charAt(0) == 'M'){
        ticPrice = regTicPrice;
    }
}
else{
 ticPrice = 0;   
}
```

Once you get the Cutsome type(senior): 50*0.9=45=ticPrice.
now again you need to apply discount on loaction(Upper): 45*0.7=31.5.=> ticPrice*0.7.  Not regTicPrice*0.7